# image processing script

Tags: python

I have a a code that i am running successfully but want to  convert a if statement so that it becomes slick. i want it to be able to go back to the beginning of the code so that it can start reading another image if it fails to open an image. the following is the code. all i have above is a connection to the database and fetching the first images

```
hDataset = gdal.Open( pszFilename, gdal.GA_ReadOnly ) 

    if hDataset is  None:

        print("gdalinfo failed - unable to open '%s'." % pszFilename )

         return 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at using a while loop or a for loop to achieve what you are after.

for example, if you have a list of files you would like try opening, something like the following may be useful: (This is not copy-paste code for you to use, just an example)

```
succesfully_opened_datasets=[]
list_of_files=[a,list,of,filenames]
for image_filename in list_of_files:
    dataset=gdal.open(image_filename,gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
    if not dataset:
        print ("gdalinfo failed....")
    else:
        succesfully_opened_datasets.append(dataset)
return succesfully_opened_datasets
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you're asking, but you could do something like that with a generator.

```
def open_images(*filenames):
    for fname in filenames:
        hDataset = fdal.Open(fname, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)

        if hDataset is not None:
            yield hDataset
        else:
            print("gdalinfo failed - unable to open '%s'." % fname)

 image_loader = open_images("a.jpg", "b.jpg")

 # to get the first image that opens correctly
 image = image_loader.next()
```

Sorry if that isn't what you were getting at.

Comment: its almost what i am looking for but the code does not work, what i actually what i want to  do is load the next image if it gdalfailed to open so that the code above it runs and does a series of processes on the image for instance read from the database the image and print it and i have managed to insert a code that updates the database to say if the image failed to open

Comment: In that case you might just need to do a loop like @matt-warren suggessted.  The above code is just an example of a generator that returns the first valid image.  You could add more to the `else` section if you need to handle a failure or process the return value.